# FCC "25 + 5 Clock" project failing audio tests 27 & 29 but work fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made the "25 + 5 Clock" for the FCC project, but although it works fine when I test it manually the automatic tests give fail flag for test 27 (sound when timer reaches "00:00") and 29 (sound stopped and rewound when clicked the reset button).

At first I wrote the "timer" function inside the setState() method (so as updater function) so I changed it so it would call setState() only with values to update the state, but it it didn't change the tests outcome (i dunno why it should but meh). The only change was when I used React v17 instead of v18 - the test 29 passed, but 27 was still failing... I even tried to understand the test bundle to find from where the fails come from, but at this point I don't understand half of the code there... Can someone explain to me why would the test fail if it works fine? Is it the way how I coded it? I wasted 2 days to make it pass, but without success. Any advice would be welcome!

Here is my code and the [codepen](https://codepen.io/prewol/pen/poxWVKy):

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.timer = this.timer.bind(this);
    this.state = {break : 5,
                 session: 25,
                 time: '25:00',
                 period: 'SESSION',
                 timer: false,
                 timerFunction: null,
                 beep: false};
  };

  handleClick(event) {
    const key = event.currentTarget.id;
    switch(key) {
      case "session-increment":
        this.setState((prev) => {{
          if (prev.session < 60 && !prev.timer) {
            let time = ''
            if (prev.session < 9) {
              time = '0' + (prev.session + 1) + ':00'
            } else {
              time = prev.session + 1 + ':00'
            }
            return {session: prev.session + 1, time: time}
          }
        }})
        break;
      case "session-decrement":
        this.setState((prev) => {{
          if (prev.session > 1 && !prev.timer) {
            let time = ''
            if (prev.session < 11) {
              time = '0' + (prev.session - 1) + ':00'
            } else {
              time = prev.session - 1 + ':00'
            }
            return {session: prev.session - 1, time: time}
          }
        }})
        break;
      case "break-increment":
        this.setState((prev) => {{
          if (prev.break < 60 && !prev.timer) {
            return {break: prev.break + 1}
          }
        }})
        break;
      case "break-decrement":
        this.setState((prev) => {{
          if (prev.break > 1 && !prev.timer) {
            return {break: prev.break - 1}
          }
        }})
        break;
      case "start_stop":
        if (this.state.timer) {
          this.setState({timer: false, timerFunction: null})
          clearInterval(this.state.timerFunction)
        } else {
          let timerFunction = setInterval(this.timer, 1000)
          this.setState({timer: true, timerFunction: timerFunction})
        }
        break;
      case "reset":
        this.setState((prev) => {{
          clearInterval(prev.timerFunction)
          document.getElementById('beep').pause()
          document.getElementById('beep').currentTime = 0
          return {break: 5, session: 25, time: '25:00', period: 'SESSION', timer: false, timerFunction: null, beep: false}
        }})
        break;
    }
  };
  timer() {
    let [m, s] = this.state.time.split(':')
    if (s == '00') {
      if (m == '00') {//reached 00:00? time for a change!
        if (this.state.period == 'SESSION') {
          let time = ''
          if (this.state.break < 10) {
            time = '0' + this.state.break + ':00'
          } else {
            time = this.state.break + ':00'
          }
          this.setState({time: time, period: 'BREAK', beep: true})
          return null
        } else {
          let time = ''
          if (this.state.session < 10) {
            time = '0' + this.state.session + ':00'
          } else {
            time = this.state.session + ':00'
          }
          this.setState({time: time, period: 'SESSION', beep: true})
          return null
        }
      }        
    }
    if (s != '00') {
      s = (Number(s) - 1).toString()
      if (Number(s) < 10) {
        s = '0' + s
      }
    } else {//reached 00 seconds
      if (m != '00') {
        m = (Number(m) - 1).toString()
        s = '59'
        if (Number(m) < 10) {
          m = '0' + m
        }
      }
    }    
    let time = m + ':' + s
    this.setState({time: time})
    if (time == '00:00') {
      document.getElementById('beep').play()
      this.setState({beep: true})
    }
    if (this.state.beep && s == '55') {
      document.getElementById('beep').pause()
      document.getElementById('beep').load()
      this.setState({time: time, beep: false})
    }
    
  }
  render() {
    const buttonIncrementStyle = {gridArea: '4 / 3 / span 1 / span 2',
                                  backgroundColor: '#72a2c0',
                                  display: 'flex',
                                  justifyContent: 'center',
                                  alignItems: 'center',
                                  height: '15px',
                                  borderRadius: '5px',
                                  boxShadow: '2px 2px 2px'};
    const buttonDecrementStyle = {gridArea: '4 / 1 / span 1 / span 2',
                                  backgroundColor: '#72a2c0',
                                  display: 'flex',
                                  justifyContent: 'center',
                                  alignItems: 'center',
                                  height: '15px',
                                  borderRadius: '5px',
                                  boxShadow: '2px 2px 2px'};
    const startStopButtonStyle = {gridArea: '5 / 4 / span 1 / span 1',
                                 display: 'flex',
                                 justifyContent: 'center',
                                 alignItems: 'center',
                                 height: '25px',
                                 backgroundColor: '#72a2c0',
                                 borderRadius: '5px',
                                 boxShadow: '2px 2px 2px'};
    const resetButtonStyle = {gridArea: '5 / 5 / span 1 / span 1',
                             display: 'flex',
                             justifyContent: 'center',
                             alignItems: 'center',
                             height: '25px',
                             backgroundColor: '#72a2c0',
                             borderRadius: '5px',
                             boxShadow: '2px 2px 2px'};
    const timerDisplayStyle = {gridArea: '2 / 2 / span 3 / span 6',
                              fontFamily: 'lcd',
                              fontSize: 65,
                               height: '85px',
                               display: 'flex',
                               justifyContent: 'center',
                               alignItems: 'center',
                               borderRadius: '5px',
                               boxShadow: '3px 3px 5px inset #000000',
                              backgroundColor: '#192e5b',
                              color: '#ffffff'};
    const clockLabelStyle = {gridArea: '1 / 3 / span 1 / span 4',
                            display: 'flex',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            height: '25px',
                            backgroundColor: '#cbd8df',
                            borderRadius: '5px'};
    const containerStyle = {display: 'grid',
                           gridTemplateColumns: '30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px',
                           gridTemplateRows: '25px 25px 25px 25px 25px 25px 25px 25px',
                           gap: '5px',
                           backgroundColor: '#3eb59d',
                           borderRadius: '10px',
                           width: '295px',
                           height: '255px',
                           alignContent: 'center',
                           justifyContent: 'center',
                           boxShadow: '10px 10px 5px'};
    const setterSStyle = {gridArea: '6 / 1 / span 3 / span 4',
                         display: 'grid',
                         gridTemplateColumns: '27.5px 27.5px 27.5px 27.5px',
                         gridTemplateRows: '15px 15px 15px 15px',
                         gap: '5px',
                         justifyContent: 'center',
                         alignItems: 'center',
                         height: '85px',
                         borderRadius: '5px',
                         backgroundColor: '#1d65a6'};
    const setterBStyle = {gridArea: '6 / 5 / span 3 / span 4',
                         display: 'grid',
                         gridTemplateColumns: '27.5px 27.5px 27.5px 27.5px',
                         gridTemplateRows: '15px 15px 15px 15px',
                         gap: '5px',
                         justifyContent: 'center',
                         alignItems: 'center',
                         height: '85px',
                         borderRadius: '5px',
                         backgroundColor: '#1d65a6'};
    const setterDisplayStyle = {gridArea: '2 / 1 / span 2 / span 4',
                                fontFamily: 'lcd',
                                fontSize: 30,
                                height: '35px',
                                width: '100%',
                                display: 'flex',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                backgroundColor: '#00743f',
                                color: '#ffffff',
                                borderRadius: '5px',
                                boxShadow: '2px 2px 2px inset #000000'};
    
    return (
          <div style={containerStyle}>
            <div style={clockLabelStyle} id={'timer-label'}>{this.state.period}</div>
            <Display displayStyle={timerDisplayStyle} id={'time-left'} content={this.state.time} />
            <Button id={'start_stop'} buttonStyle={startStopButtonStyle} onClick={this.handleClick} >
             <Start />
            </Button>
            <Button id={'reset'} buttonStyle={resetButtonStyle} onClick={this.handleClick}>
              <Reset />
            </Button>
            <Setter id={'session-label'} setterStyle={setterSStyle} label={'SESSION'}>
              <Display id={'session-length'} displayStyle={setterDisplayStyle} content={this.state.session} />
              <Button id={'session-increment'} buttonStyle={buttonIncrementStyle} onClick={this.handleClick} children={'+'} />
              <Button id={'session-decrement'} buttonStyle={buttonDecrementStyle} onClick={this.handleClick} children={"-"} />
            </Setter>
            <Setter id={'break-label'} setterStyle={setterBStyle} label={'BREAK'}>
              <Display id={'break-length'} displayStyle={setterDisplayStyle} content={this.state.break} />
              <Button id={'break-increment'} buttonStyle={buttonIncrementStyle} onClick={this.handleClick} children={'+'} />
              <Button id={'break-decrement'} buttonStyle={buttonDecrementStyle} onClick={this.handleClick} children={"-"} />
            </Setter>
            <audio id={'beep'} preload={'auto'}>
              <source src={'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/cdn/master/build/testable-projects-fcc/audio/BeepSound.wav'} />
            </audio>
          </div>
    );
  };
}
function Display(props) {
  return (
  <div style={props.displayStyle} id={props.id}>
    {props.content}
  </div>
  )
}
function Button(props) {
  return (
  <div style={props.buttonStyle} id={props.id} onClick={props.onClick}>
    {props.children}
  </div>
  )
}
function Setter(props) {
  return (
  <div style={props.setterStyle}>
    <div id={props.id} style={{display:'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '15px', gridArea: '1 / 1 / span 1 / span 4'}}>{props.label}</div>
    {props.children}
  </div>
  )
}
function Start() {
  return (
    <div style={{width:'20px', height:'20px'}}>
      <svg height='20' width='20'>
        <polygon points='0,0 0,20 10,10' />
        <line x1='13' x2='13' y1='1' y2='19' style={{stroke:"black", strokeWidth:3}} />
        <line x1='18' x2='18' y1='19' y2='1' style={{stroke:"black", strokeWidth:3}} />
      </svg>
    </div>)
}
function Reset() {
  return (
    <div style={{width:'20px', height:'20px'}}>
      <svg height='20' width='20'>
        <line x1='1' x2='19' y1='1' y2='19' style={{stroke:"black", strokeWidth:3}} />
        <line x1='1' x2='19' y1='19' y2='1' style={{stroke:"black", strokeWidth:3}} />
      </svg>
    </div>
  )
}
root.render(<Clock />)
```